# App for playing multiple tracks from different sources simultaneously

Tags: ios, applications

I have a 6 generation iPod touch and am looking for a specific app.

I want to be able to play some track in the background, let's say song A, and then not only that it'll keep playing when I minimize the app - I also need it to keep playing while I play different tracks on the Music app, for example.

Song A (from the app I'm looking for) and Song B (from my iPod's music) should be playing simultaneously.

Is that even possible on iOS?

Comment: What you are looking for is called a soundboard app. It works if you have both tracks in your collection. You are then able to play them (and more) simultaneously through one app. Maybe that's a valid alternative for you. Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Audio playback is handled as a background task in iOS. Only one app is allowed to playback background audio in iOS at a time.

Music playing apps usually programmed to continue playback even when in background (i.e. while you are using some other app, such as Safari). As you are looking to play music via two different apps, it will not be possible if both of them are programmed to support background audio playback mode.

However, when one of the apps plays back music while not supporting background mode (such as a game app), it will be possible to playback music simultaneously from two apps, i.e. one supporting playback in background while the other is frontmost.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I want to listen to audiobooks while tracks are playing, and iBooks does support background mode. Maybe I need to look for a music player that does not. Do u happen to know one?

Comment: @St.Mount One question per question. If you want to ask a software recommendation question - feel free to ask that as a new discussion point. Be sure to up vote and accept helpful answers and accept one should it address the question.